# While reading the line using item reader, when the line starts with token the file is not read

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch item reader and delimited tokeniser to read a file and map the tokens to Java objects, when the line starts with token the file is not read.

```
#123#456#789#
#647#847#938#
#737#938#737#
```

Below file works.

```
123#124#647#648#
123#737#747#747#
272#848#848#838#
```

Below file doesn't work. How to read the below file.

```
#123#456#789#
#647#847#938#
#737#938#737#
```

Comment: In your title, what is "line ising"? What kind of `ItemReader` are you using? One supplied by Spring Batch (e.g. `FlatFileItemReader`) or a custom one? If it's the latter, how did you implement the `read()` method? Finally, the way you have presented the examples: are the spaces supposed to be new lines? (I think so, because the incorrectly formatted block of lines (surround by back ticks) suggests this.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `FlatFileItemReader` considers lines starting `#` to be comments and does not parse them.

You can override this by passing a suitable String array to `FlatFileItemReader::setComments`. The array should contain all prefixes of lines that should be considered as comments. If your input does not contain any comments, you can set it to an empty array.